# Return true if the passed item is present in all the arrays inside - fails to return false?

Tags: javascript

The tests return true, but fails to return false. Could someone please explain me why?

```
function isItemOmnipresent(arrayOfArrays, item) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfArrays.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; i < arrayOfArrays[i].length; j++) {
      if (arrayOfArrays[i][j] === item) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks awfully close to an attempt to check if every item of every array matches `item`, or do you just want to see if the item is present *at least once* in every array?

Comment: Just once mate in every array mate

Comment: Maybe provide a complete code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: `return` ends the function. So if the item is present in at least one of the Arrays, it returns `true`.

You could do it like this:

```
function isItemOmnipresent(arrayOfArrays, item) {
  return arrayOfArrays.every(arr => arr.includes(item));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the function will end when the interpreter comes across a `return`, you should only return once the *whole array* fails the tests. Tweaking your `for` loop method, check a flag that gets set when a matching item is found:

```
function isItemOmnipresent(arrayOfArrays, item) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfArrays.length; i++) {
    let found = false;
    for (let j = 0; i < arrayOfArrays[i].length; j++) {
      if (arrayOfArrays[i][j] === item) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate, I was trying to go for this in the first place, unfortunately I went wrong somewhere but it's good to know I was on the right lines. Thank you very much for your help, I think it's time I call it a night!

Comment: Thank you one again I was just about to ask you for more help!